# how to solve NSPredicate error 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection 8 (not a collection)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I tried to predicate my coredate based on the mood on the initial queries all the moods are set to 8.
I will be calling from 0 - 7 every sec to update the tableview.

but I got

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection 8 (not a collection)'
```

Should I use CONTAINS or other operator to predicate?

```
NSString* filter = @"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@";
NSPredicate *getMoodPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:filter, @"mood", mood];
NSLog(@"getmood %@",getMoodPred); //getmood mood CONTAINS[cd] "7"
NSArray *getMoodArray = [[VPPCoreData sharedInstance]allObjectsForEntity:@"Song" orderBy:Nil filteredBy:getMoodPred];
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The probably means that the `mood` attribute is stored as Number, not as String. "CONTAINS" works only with strings. The following predicate should work:

```
NSNumber *mood = @(7);
NSString *filter = @"%K == %@";
NSPredicate *getMoodPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:filter, @"mood", mood];
```

using `NSNumber` on the rhs and `==` as comparator.

Comment: suppose , i have a field with integer value 2000. Then if i write exactly 2000, it shows the result. Is there any way to get substring match for the integer field ? I want to get the value when i type 2 or 20 or 200. How to skip writing full number ? Is there any way ?

Comment: @JamshedAlam: I do not think that is possible. Substring matching works only with strings, not with integers.