# How to filter an array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, filter

I want to filter below array of disc, here is my code but app is crashing

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Id contains[c] %@ ", string];
NSArray *result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

return result;

```
[{
    "Id": 1,
    "VoteCode": "1"
}, {
    "Id": 2,
    "VoteCode": "1"
}, {
    "Id": 3,
    "VoteCode": "1"
}, {
    "Id": 8,
    "VoteCode": "12345"
}, {
    "Id": 9,
    "VoteCode": "103"
}, {
    "Id": 10,
    "VoteCode": "12345"
}]
```

Comment: could you post the exception causing the crash?

Comment: Can't use in/contains operator with collection 1 (not a collection)

Comment: the "Id" has numbers, but if im not mistaken "contain" only works with strings.

Comment: This answer might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20607234/906830

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate format is wrong. The `CONTAINS` operator is for string comparison (see the [predicate programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB)), but your "Id" key in each dictionary is not a string, it's a number.

You can either store your Id's as strings, or use a different predicate; for example:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K ==[cd] %@ ", @"Id", @1];
```